# Where should I initialize the in-app billing service in Android using MVP design pattern

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, mvp

Where should I initialize the in-app billing service in Android using MVP design pattern?
Should I do it in the presenter? I read that we should not write android-specific code in the presenter, it must be plain java.
Plus, in-app billing has lots of dependencies with the android activity class. If I put the logic in the View, I will violate the design pattern.

Please help.